# Pointer truncation with 'realloc()' on OS/X in JNI library

Tags: c, macos, gcc, java-native-interface, realloc

I have the following piece of code in a JNI library. This compiles and works as expected under Linux (32 and 64 bit) on both ARM and x86 architectures. I've removed some error checking and other code for brevity.

```
  // Globals:
  //
  // uint8_t *g_assets (initialised to NULL)
  // uint32_t g_nextIndex (initialised to 0)
  //
  // Parameters:
  //
  // uint32_t size (number of extra bytes to allocate)

  // Try and reallocate the array to fit the new data
  uint8_t *pNew = (uint8_t *)realloc(g_assets, g_nextIndex + size);
  if(pNew==NULL)
    return -1;
  g_assets = pNew;
```

On OS/X the call to realloc() succeeds (does not return NULL) but any attempt to access the contents of g_assets results in a message like:

```
Invalid memory access of location 0x72911f20 rip=0x7fff90b35fd7
```

By adding some printf statements to show the values of the pointers it seems they are either returned as 32 bit values or as a 64 bit value with the highest 32 bits set (eg: 0xffffffffcb41cc80).

I changed the code around a bit to the following:

```
  void *pBuffer;
  if(g_assets==NULL)
    pBuffer = malloc(size);
  else
    pBuffer = realloc(g_assets, g_nextIndex + size);
  if(pBuffer==NULL)
    return -1;
  g_assets = pBuffer;
```

On the first invocation the malloc() call returns a full 64 bit pointer (and writes to the memory don't trigger invalid memory access) but subsequent calls to realloc() to try and extend the size of the buffer exhibit the same problem as before. Some sample debug output I produced during testing is as follows:

```
// Add first item, 32 bytes long
addAsset: g_assets = 0x0, g_nextIndex = 0, size = 32
addAsset: pBuffer = 0x7f8372912260, g_assets = 0x7f8372912260, g_nextIndex = 0, size = 32
// Add second item, 450 bytes long
addAsset: g_assets = 0x7f8372912260, g_nextIndex = 32, size = 450
addAsset: pBuffer = 0x72911f00, g_assets = 0x72911f00, g_nextIndex = 32, size = 450
```

As you can see, realloc() seems to be truncating the pointer to 32 bits for some reason. Any help would be appreciated as this is getting very frustrating.

My environment:

daphne:java shane$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)

daphne:java shane$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

The C code is being compiled through autoconf/automake.

Comment: Are you including the appropriate headers? (<stdlib.h>) Remove the cast from realloc and make sure no warnings about trying to make pointer from int without a cast show up. That's usually the cause of such truncation.

Comment: As Wiz said. The typecast in return of `realloc` probably hides that there is no proper prototype for the function and the compiler assumes everything is of the default type `int`.

Comment: `pBuffer = 0x72911f00` look like a 64 bit pointer truncate to 32 bit. Did you have some warning when compiling your code?

Comment: @Wiz - that was the problem. Thanks, something so simple and I overlooked it :( I'm still not sure why malloc() worked though, or why the same code ran fine on 64 bit Linux though.

Comment: @ShaneG Note that like always, I tell people to **NOT** cast the result of realloc() and malloc(). (I know [CERT says not to](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM02-C.+Immediately+cast+the+result+of+a+memory+allocation+function+call+into+a+pointer+to+the+allocated+type), however I see this bug WAY too often and not casting it is the _ONLY_ way to catch it.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was failing to include  to get the correct prototypes for realloc(), malloc(), etc. Adding that solved the issue. Thanks to Wiz and tristopia for pointing this out.

I'm still not clear why the problem only manifested on OS/X (which is what led me to suspect something more complicated).

Comment: Apple configures its compilers to emit 64-bit code by default. Some Linux compiler emit 32-bit code by default although they are running on a 64-bit platform.